# Where is "Enable Library Loading" Developer Options on Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

On Release Note of Google VR SDK for Unity v1.40 (April 2017)
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes

> Note: You must enable dynamic library loading in VrCore to get the
>   latest C++ GVR Updates. To do this, go to Settings > Developer Options
>
> > Enable Library Loading. If Developer Options are not visible, tap 7 times on Build Version.

I'm looking for on Nexus 5X(7.0), Nexus 6P(O Preview), Pixel XL(7.1),
I cannot find "Enable Library Loading" setting in Developer Options.
What's mean this?

Comment: Wow. `"Enable Library Loading"` as a phrase *only exists on that release notes page* (i.e. I did a google search and it was the only English result, the other result was in Japanese and was basically the same info). It might be so new that no Android OS *has* that option yet.

Comment: thx to your comment, Draco18s. I did not found in Android O Preview (Nexus 6P), so next O Preview is coming, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is only available from the **VR** developer options.

To access the option :

1. Open a VR app, for example the Daydream app for the Pixel XL
2. Go into the settings menu, either via a regular menu (in the Daydream app for example), or by pressing the small gear in the top right corner if you are in stereo mode[image: Position of the settings button in stereo mode]
3. You should see a settings menu with "Build Version" at the bottom of the list : tap on it several time to activate the developer mode
4. Once the developer mode is activated, you should find the option "Enable GVR SDK Library loading" in it.